# Android 4 UI in old version

Tags: android, user-interface, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Is there is any variant to create custom UI in Android 2.2 or Android 2.3.3 so that it looks like in Android 4.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find the resources used by any version of Android at `../your_sdk_path/platforms/android-xx/data/res/` path, if you have previously downloaded this `xx` package with Android SDK Manager. For example, Android 4.0.3 resources could be found in `../your_sdk_path/platforms/android-15/data/res/` dir.

Comment: I think that this is don't what I want. For exemple - I want to Tab Layout in my application looks like in Android 4.0, even if an application on Android 2.2. How to do it?

Comment: If you decided to make your application look like running on Android 4.0 then you will have to customize all UI-components, including those related to tabs (resources for which could be also found in the dir mentioned above).